# Adding WMS using CartoDB Editor?

Tags: wms, carto

Does anyone know how to add a WMS layer using the CartoDB Editor?

I was told that it's possible to create a WMS table and then add each layer as a row in the table.

But, I cannot figure out exactly how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a WMS layer on a map as a basemap. In the CartoDB [documentation](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor/maps/#including-an-external-basemap) it is explained how to add it form the CartoDB Editor.

Also, you can use [Leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/) and [CartoDB.js](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js/) to add WMS maps in your html file with [L.tileLayer.wms](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms) option.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  The WMSs have to be overlays with the normal interactivity (toggle on & off, view attributes in a popup window, change \transparency) so adding them as basemaps will not work.  Also, I'm not very good at javascript so Leaftet.js and CardoDB.js are not the preferred options.

When I asked one of the guys there, he seemed to suggest that it was possible to list each layer as a row in a postgis table, and add them to the map that way.  Do you have any idea how that might work?